# How to display only Google Fonts in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-management

Is it possible to show only Google Fonts in the font drop down without using a 3rd party tool?

Comment: You either have to have google fonts mixed with all the other fonts in the font list or use third party tools.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very short; No.

There is no way to sort fonts in photoshop, other than manually disabling certain fonts in your OS. Which is very hacky and probably not the best idea.

Comment: From a scripting standpoint, wouldn't it be technically possible to lookup the array of fonts that is currently loaded, filter those out using meta data properties? After refilling the array and calling the fonts.RefreshFonts() method photoshop *should* load only those. Since photoshop uses a ooj - design, this *should* be possible with JScript, shouldnt it?

Comment: @beggarboy that's a very good suggestion, I do not have sufficient scripting experience to confirm this though.

Comment: As I said, *should*, I can't confirm either as I have only seen parts of the documentation, I haven't tried to script something in PS till today. I don't have a copy of ps installed in my workplace, so I'd have to check this at home when I have some spare time. The only thing that would break my logic, would be if ps pulls it's array of fonts directly from the system through a stream. If it doesn't use the local modified variables when calling a .fontRefresh() method, you're screwed. Dealing with filestream manipulation is the exact opposite of fun. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this natively in Photoshop no. This is *exactly* what a font manager is for.

I use [FontExplorerX](http://www.fontexplorerx.com), which is great, but there are plenty of alternatives available and a number of previous Q&As about font management.

With a font manager you can group your fonts in to meaningful sets which you can enable and disable as you wish, so it should be as easy as a few clicks to enable your Google fonts and disable all others (although there will be some system fonts which you can't disable as your OS needs them to run).